# How can I add onKeyPress event to react material-ui select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to move to the next field in a form when key enter is pressed.
I tried putting onKeyPress in the element's props, in the prop inputProps and in MenuProps but it didn't work. The menu to choose an option keeps opening.
Is there any way to do this?

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      {...props}
      onKeyPress={(e) => console.log(e.key)}
    >
      {...menuItems}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps the `onChange` event

Comment: You may want to look into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mousetrap

Comment: ass you can see here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8191, its an issue of this component, and you can't do it using this option